# Filtering CSV file of URLS based on String Match

Tags: python, unix, csv, awk, grep

I have a large CSV file with several thousand lines, no header with each line a separate URL.

Some example lines:

```html
http://www.whitehouse.gov/the-press-office/2012/01/27/remarks-president-college-affordability-ann-arbor-michigan 
http://www.whitehouse.gov/the-press-office/2012/01/26/remarks-first-lady-dnc-event-palm-beach-fl 
http://www.whitehouse.gov/the-press-office/2012/01/26/remarks-president-american-energy-aurora-colorado
http://www.whitehouse.gov/the-press-office/2012/01/26/remarks-first-lady-dnc-event-sarasota-fl
http://www.whitehouse.gov/the-press-office/2012/01/26/remarks-first-lady-goya-foods-miplato-announcement-tampa-fl 
http://www.whitehouse.gov/the-press-office/2012/01/26/remarks-president-american-made-energy
http://www.whitehouse.gov/the-press-office/2012/01/25/remarks-president-intel-ocotillo-campus-chandler-az 
http://www.whitehouse.gov/the-press-office/2012/01/25/remarks-first-lady-school-lunch-standards-announcement 
http://www.whitehouse.gov/the-press-office/2012/01/25/remarks-president-conveyor-engineering-and-manufacturing-cedar-rapids-io
http://www.whitehouse.gov/the-press-office/2012/01/24/remarks-president-state-union-address 
http://www.whitehouse.gov/the-press-office/2012/01/23/remarks-president-welcoming-2011-stanley-cup-champion-boston-bruins 
http://www.whitehouse.gov/the-press-office/2012/01/21/weekly-address-creating-jobs-boosting-tourism
http://www.whitehouse.gov/the-press-office/2012/01/19/remarks-president-campaign-event-2 
http://www.whitehouse.gov/the-press-office/2012/01/19/remarks-president-campaign-event-1 
http://www.whitehouse.gov/the-press-office/2012/01/19/remarks-president-campaign-event-0
http://www.whitehouse.gov/the-press-office/2012/01/19/remarks-president-campaign-event 
http://www.whitehouse.gov/the-press-office/2012/01/19/remarks-president-unveiling-strategy-help-boost-travel-and-tourism
http://www.whitehouse.gov/the-press-office/2012/01/17/remarks-president-and-first-lady-honoring-2011-world-champion-st-louis-c
```

I would like to filter these URLs such that I can pipe the results into a separate CSV file. I have tried multiple grep and awk options but I keep getting far too many results that do not match my quoted string.

For example, I would like

```
grep "remarks-president" speechurls.csv >> remarks-president_urls.csv
```

to return all urls that have only "remarks-president" in the URL. Example:

```html
http://www.whitehouse.gov/the-press-office/2012/01/27/remarks-president-college-affordability-ann-arbor-michigan 
http://www.whitehouse.gov/the-press-office/2012/01/26/remarks-president-american-energy-aurora-colorado
http://www.whitehouse.gov/the-press-office/2012/01/26/remarks-president-american-made-energy
http://www.whitehouse.gov/the-press-office/2012/01/25/remarks-president-intel-ocotillo-campus-chandler-az 
http://www.whitehouse.gov/the-press-office/2012/01/25/remarks-president-conveyor-engineering-and-manufacturing-cedar-rapids-io
http://www.whitehouse.gov/the-press-office/2012/01/24/remarks-president-state-union-address 
http://www.whitehouse.gov/the-press-office/2012/01/23/remarks-president-welcoming-2011-stanley-cup-champion-boston-bruins 
http://www.whitehouse.gov/the-press-office/2012/01/19/remarks-president-campaign-event-2 
http://www.whitehouse.gov/the-press-office/2012/01/19/remarks-president-campaign-event-1 
http://www.whitehouse.gov/the-press-office/2012/01/19/remarks-president-campaign-event-0
http://www.whitehouse.gov/the-press-office/2012/01/19/remarks-president-campaign-event 
http://www.whitehouse.gov/the-press-office/2012/01/19/remarks-president-unveiling-strategy-help-boost-travel-and-tourism
http://www.whitehouse.gov/the-press-office/2012/01/17/remarks-president-and-first-lady-honoring-2011-world-champion-st-louis-c
```

Similarly

```
grep "remarks-first-lady"  speechurls.csv >> remarks-first-lady_urls.csv
```

should return all those speeches with "remarks-first-lady" in the URL.

Other specifications I have tried, have not helped.

```
grep -w -l "remarks-president" speechurls.csv >> remarks-president_urls.csv
```

I have also tried the following without much luck.

```
awk -F, '$1 ~ /remarks-president|president-obama/ {print}' speechurls.csv

fgrep -w "remarks-vice-president" speechurls.csv
```

I am not entirely sure what to do about this problem. Any help would be much appreciated. If there is a better way to do this in Python, I am also open to that solution.

Comment: Can you edit the question to show the output you are expecting from `grep "remarks-president" speechurls.csv ` ?

Comment: Sure thing, updated to reflect expected output.

Comment: I don't understand. You are running the right tool with the right options and you are getting the expected output so what's the problem? Please edit your question to show sample input, the command you are running, and the output you are getting that you DON'T want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Situations like these are fun to whip up a quick and dirty python script. I believe the following should work.

```
import csv 
with open('speechurls.csv', 'r') as f:
    for row in csv.reader(f):
        if 'remarks-president' in row[0]:
            with open('remarks-president_urls.csv','a') as f1: f1.write("{}\n".format(row[0]))
        elif 'remarks-first-lady' in row[0]:
            with open('remarks-first-lady_urls.csv', 'a') as f2: f2.write("{}\n".format(row[0]))
        else:
            pass
```

It's not pretty, it doesn't have an elegant design, but it works and seems to fit what you are asking for.

Comment: Thank you Muttonchop! That works as expected! The only strange error I got was the returned error "_csv.Error: new-line character seen in unquoted field." If I change 'r' to 'rU' in the script, however, it does exactly what I wanted!

Comment: I'm glad it helped! If it answered your question please consider marking it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Could one of you please explain what the question was about? What was it the OP was trying and failing to accomplish with his grep commands?

Comment: To clarify, what I was trying to do with the grep command was filter a large CSV file of urls into several other filtered CSVs. The problem was that the original grep method was returning some of the urls I wanted and many of the urls I did not want. The original answer by @Muttonchop worked exactly as I wanted. I modified his code and inserted it as an answer below. Thanks again for everyone's help!

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite get the question."grep "remarks-first-lady" speechurls.csv" should work just fine in this situation.

The problem you have maybe comes from ">>", ">>" means to append new lines to an existing file and if you want a file with just the output of the command, you will need to use ">" instead of ">>".

If you can also indicate what's going wrong with your code I might identify your problem better.

Comment: I intended to but I don't have the privilege.

Comment: Thanks, I believe the threshold is 50 and I'm close now.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to post an update to my question. Thanks to the help of @Muttonchop, I have been able to solve the CSV filtering problem.

This python solution works well. Modifying @Muttonchop 's initial response, here is the full code I ended up with:

```
    def filterSpeechURL():
        import csv 
        with open('speechurls.csv', 'rU') as f:
            for row in csv.reader(f):

                #Filter President Obama
                if 'remarks-president' in row[0]:
                    with open('__president_urls.csv','a') as f1: f1.write("{}\n".format(row[0]))
                elif 'weekly-address' in row[0]:
                    with open('__president_urls.csv','a') as f1: f1.write("{}\n".format(row[0]))
                elif 'letter' in row[0]:
                    with open('__president_urls.csv','a') as f1: f1.write("{}\n".format(row[0]))
                elif 'statement-president' in row[0]:
                    with open('__president_urls.csv','a') as f1: f1.write("{}\n".format(row[0]))
                elif 'president-obama' in row[0]:
                    with open('__president_urls.csv','a') as f1: f1.write("{}\n".format(row[0]))
                elif 'excerpts-president' in row[0]:
                    with open('__president_urls.csv','a') as f1: f1.write("{}\n".format(row[0]))


                #Filter First Lady
                elif 'remarks-first-lady' in row[0]:
                    with open('__first-lady_urls.csv', 'a') as f2: f2.write("{}\n".format(row[0]))


                #Filter VP
                elif 'vice-president' in row[0]:
                    with open('__vice_president_urls.csv', 'a') as f2: f2.write("{}\n".format(row[0]))


                #Filter Jill Biden
                elif 'jill' in row[0]:
                    with open('__second-lady_urls.csv', 'a') as f2: f2.write("{}\n".format(row[0]))
                elif 'dr-biden' in row[0]:
                    with open('__second-lady_urls.csv', 'a') as f2: f2.write("{}\n".format(row[0]))


                #Filter Everthing Else
                else:
                    with open('__other_urls.csv', 'a') as f2: f2.write("{}\n".format(row[0]))

    filterSpeechURL()
```